# Fine grained authorization in ServiceStack API

Tags: authorization, servicestack

I am developing a large API surface using ServiceStack and I'm addressing the question of authorization.  End-users need the ability to customize the rights given to various roles at the API request level, ie. which request messages/http verbs that role can call.

For this reason, I plan to keep roles out of code and not use ServiceStack's RequiresRole attribute.  I plan to store role/permission relationships in database.

I also use JWT.  Because of the large size of the API, I'm concerned about using RequiresPermission attribute with ServiceStack's built in permissions system as I know permissions are stuffed in the JWT and I don't won't to bloat the headers too much.  Users may have hundreds or even thousands of permissions.

I am considering

1)  Storing user role claims but not permission claims in the JWT.
2)  Creating a custom request filter that checks to see if the user has the permission needed (from cached DB table) based on their role in the JWT.

Does this sound like a reasonable approach for implementing my authorization needs in ServiceStack?  What drawbacks may I be missing?  Is there a way to accomplish my goals using the built in ServiceStack authorization tools without resorting to a custom request filter or bloating my JWTs too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that sounds like a reasonable approach, if you're using JWT you should be mindful of the number of roles/permissions a user has as it impacts the payload size of each request, therefore resorting to use app-level permissions disconnected from ServiceStack's roles/permissions is a good approach.